# Python Script: Pausing Typing at Periods?

Tags: python, pyautogui

My goal in this code is to make my computer print an input and stop at periods like a normal person would. But it totally skips over it. Does anyone have any ideas?

```py
import pyautogui
import time
import random

word = input("Text: ")

print("Starting in:")
for countdown in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(countdown)
    time.sleep(1)

def find_letters(word):
    result_list = []
    for number in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        # Find the letter at the current position
        result = word[number - 1]
        result_list.append(result)
    return result_list

# Example usage:
results = find_letters(word)

for number, result in enumerate(results, start=1):
    if result == ".":
        sleep_time = random.uniform(15, 30)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
    else:
        sleep_time = random.uniform(0.2, 0.5)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
    pyautogui.write(result)
```

Thanks

Comment: Your `find_letters(word)` is equivalent to just `list(word)`

Comment: Your `for number, result` loop never uses `number`. What is it for?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work, although you should write the character BEFORE sleeping, not after. Your code will pause before the period.

Comment: Why do you even need to convert the word to a list? You can loop over a string, and it will process the characters.

Comment: Honestly, idk, Im just trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Write the character before sleeping, not after.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random

text = input("Text: ")

print("Starting in:")
for countdown in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(countdown)
    time.sleep(1)

for c in text:
    pyautogui.write(c)
    if c == ".":
        sleep_time = random.uniform(15, 30)
    else:
        sleep_time = random.uniform(0.2, 0.5)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
print()
```

Comment: Hello barmar, the reason I am using pyautogui is I want my computer to automatically type it into a document to make it look like a human typing.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why your code isn't working. I've replace `print()` with `pyautogui.write()` in my simplified code, does it work?